# Setting the default time for UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a date picker which is used to select `day/month/year`. It does not display time. I'm using the date to schedule a local notification at 9am on the date selected. How do I set a 'default' time on UIDatePicker so that when I call `datePicker.date` it returns the user selected `yyyy/mm/dd + 9am`. Currently the time attached by default to a UIDatePicker seems to be random.

**Working code based on pseudocode in answer**

```
NSDate *date = _datePicker.date;

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
[components setHour:9];
[components setMinute:0];

NSDate *dateWithTime = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: Time appears to be 17:00 UTC to me? Is that what you mean by random? I was looking for some reference in the documentation as to why 17:00 UTC should be special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this on the datePicker. But you can manipulate the result. You can use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to change the time of a date.

Pseudocode:

```
NSDate *date = datePicker.date;
NSCalendar *cal = gregorian calendar;
NSDateComponents *components = [cal componentsFromDate:date];
components.hour = 11;
components.minuts = 14;
components.seconds = 0;
NSDate *dateWithTime11_14 = [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thanks. I used the code and it works. I'll post the working code in my question.